# How to return simplejson in Python

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I am a noob and I am working on a **Python** project that uses json. 
My goal is to call an `object ("object.json()")` and get the data.

The only thing is *I can only import* **simplejson** and *not import json*.

*How do I call on an object with simplejson* `e.g("object.simplejson())` <----- Obviously not right but this is just an example.

Btw I am using  **MAC Sierra 10.12.6**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `dumps` method:

```
import simplejson
encoded = simplejson.dumps(myobject)
```